# question about class derivation in c++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

i want to know some things about class derivation in c++
so i have super class x and an inherited class y
and i did this

```
class x{
    public:a;
    private:b;
    protected:c;
}    
class y:public x{
    public:d;
}
```

in this case how y can access a,b,and c and by how i mean(public,protected,private)

the second case:

```
class x{
    public:a;
    private:b;
    protected:c;
}    
class y:private x{
    public:d;
}
```

the same question?

the third case:

```
class x{
    public:a;
    private:b;
    protected:c;
}    
class y:protected x{
    public:d;
}
```

again the same question?

sorry i think i wrote too much
bye

Comment: If you don't have one, I recommend getting one of the beginner books recommended in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 5):

1. In all forms of inheritance:

   - `y` can look up to its base-class (`x`) and see `public` and `protected`.
   - Derived classes of `y` can see its `public` and `protected` members.
   - Users of `y` can see its `public` members.
   - Nobody can see anyone else's `private`s, unless they're `friend`s.
2. In public inheritance:

   - users of `y` can look up to `x` and see `public`.
3. In protected inheritance:

   - both `public` and `protected` parts of `x` become `protected` in `y`
   - Derived classes of `y` can see them.
   - Users of `y` cannot see them.
4. In private inheritance:

   - both `public` and `protected` parts of `x` become `private` in `y`:
   - Derived lasses of `y` cannot see them.
   - Users of `y` cannot see them.
   - Private inheritance is essentially the same as composition (a private data member).

[This C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html) has good information on private and protected inheritance.

Comment: In the land of C++, friends can see your privates. Never say never. ;-)

Comment: Nice answer.  Thorough, complete, succint.

Answer (score 0):

- A derived class can only access public and protected members of the base class. It cannot access the private members of the base class.
- private/public/protected inheritance affects how the members inherited from the base class (`X`) are accessible to the "users" of the derived class (`Y`); now, the users could be a class derived from this derived class.
- **private inheritance** is akin to declaring the public and protected members of the base class as private in the derived class.
- `**protected interitance**` is akin to declaring the public and protected members of the base class as protected in the derived class.
- `**public inheritance**` makes the public members of the base class public in the derived class; but the *protected members of the base class remain protected* in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

- Derived classes cannot access private members of the base class unless the derived class is a friend of the base class.
- Inheritance permissions:

  - Public - all non-private members of the base class retain their permissions (base: public, derived: public; base: protected, derived: protected)
  - Protected - all public members of the base class become protected in the derived class; protected members in the base class are still protected (base: public, derived: protected; base: protected, derived: protected)
  - Private - all non-private members of the base class become private in the derived class (base: public, derived: private; base: protected, derived: private)

I can't stress enough the fact that private members of a base class are inaccessible by a derived class unless that derived class is declared to be a friend in the base class.